# How to set limits on the colour range in heatmap or clustergram in matlab?

Tags: matlab, heatmap

When I create a basic clustergram object from a matrix D in matlab with

`h = clustergram(D)`

how can I set the colour range to [0,1]? I have tried

`set(h,'Symmetric',false,'DisplayRange',1)`

but it doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: what color range? what do you want to achieve? `DisplayRange` has nothing to do with colors.

Comment: have you tried `clim`?

Comment: I agree that clim may work, but I do not know if clustergram require specific syntax. Does this problem occur for ordinary plots as well, so to say is it colormap specific?

Comment: The colour range of the heatmap. I would like to do the equivalent of `imagesc(Matrix,[0, 1])` but I cannot find the corresponding option for the clustergram function.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this (if I understood you correctly!)

```
colorbar('YTickLabel',{'100%','90%','80%','70%','60%','50%','40%','30%','20%','10%','0%'})
```